# Are trees of bounded height well-quasi-ordered by the subgraph relation?

Tags: graph-theory

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, are finite rooted trees of height at most $k$ well-quasi-ordered by the subgraph relation? Only embeddings sending root to root are allowed.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I believe/hope that the statement is true. Maybe Kruskal can help: Let an infinite sequence of trees be given, so that no tree is subgraph of another. By Kruskal's Theorem, rooted trees are wqo by the topological minor relation. Therefore, our sequence contains an infinite ascending subsequence wrt to this relation. It feels like this sequence must contain trees of unbounded height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows by induction on $k$ from [Higman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma).

Specifically, if we think of a tree $T$ of height $\le k$ as a finite sequence of trees of height $\le k-1$ (the subtrees rooted at the children of the root of $T$), then ordering these finite sequences by embedding, with the subgraph ordering on elements of the sequences, gives us the subgraph ordering on trees of height $\le k$. (You should check this.)

Well, technically, this will give you the subgraph ordering on *ordered* trees: rooted trees in which the children of each node are given an order. But this is a sub-relation of the relation we want, so that's fine.